# Sistema de follow users php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Boas gente,

Preciso de fazer um sistema de follow para os utilizadores do meu site como notificações mas nunca fiz e não sei por onde começar, precisava de uma ideia de como posso fazer este sistema.

Comment: Acho que você deve aprender sobre [Grafos](http://tiagomadeira.com/2006/01/representando-grafos-na-programacao/) depois é só uma questão de como persistir um grafo em uma base de dados relacional

Answer (score 1):

Você vai precisar de uma relação `Many-to-Many` básica no seu banco (um usuário pode ser seguido por `0-n` usuários, e pode seguir `0-n` usuários). Basicamente, você vai precisar de uma tabela que armazene o `follower` e o `followed`, segue um exemplo dessas tabelas:

```
mysql> desc usuario;
+---------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| Field   | Type        | Null | Key | Default           | Extra          |
+---------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| id      | int(10)     | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment |
| nome    | varchar(75) | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
| created | timestamp   | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |                |
+---------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+

mysql> desc conexao;
+----------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id       | int(10) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| follower | int(10) | NO   | MUL | 0       |                |
| followed | int(10) | NO   | MUL | 0       |                |
+----------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

**Explicando:** na tabela `usuario` você vai ter os dados quaisquer de seus utilizadores como qualquer tabela de usuários padrão, na sua tabela de relacionamento `conexao`, você irá armazenar o `id` do usuário a ser seguido e o do usuário seguidor (`followed` e `follower` respectivamente).

**Exemplo de consulta para ver quem segue o usuário x:**

```
SELECT usuario.nome
  FROM conexao
 INNER JOIN usuario ON conexao.follower = usuario.id
 WHERE conexao.followed = @usuario_x_id;
```

**Código `CREATE` e `INSERT` dessa resposta:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `usuario` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nome` varchar(75) NOT NULL,
  `created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `usuario` (`id`, `nome`, `created`) VALUES
    (1, 'Eduardo', '2015-02-03 16:11:22'),
    (2, 'Maria', '2015-02-03 16:11:29'),
    (3, 'João', '2015-02-03 16:11:36');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `conexao` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `follower` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `followed` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `FK__usuario` (`follower`),
  KEY `FK__usuario_2` (`followed`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK__usuario` FOREIGN KEY (`follower`) REFERENCES `usuario` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK__usuario_2` FOREIGN KEY (`followed`) REFERENCES `usuario` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `conexao` (`id`, `follower`, `followed`) VALUES
    (1, 1, 2),
    (2, 1, 3),
    (3, 2, 3),
    (4, 3, 1);
```